# How to avoid infinite delay in web synchronous web service call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spotify

I am using Search function from spotify apps API to search tracks for my app. For that I had set pagesize property to 150.

Code for this is as follows,

```
var search = new models.Search(searchquery);

search.localResults = models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.APPEND;

search.pageSize=50;
```

I am using Collection object from spotify apps API to store searched tracks.

For each searched track I am calling LastFM's Web service synchronously (i. e. async: false).

(Here I don't want to use asynchronous web service call)

I am using javascript array to store the response from LasFM web service.

But sometimes this is causing an infinite delay to fetch the response.

I have tried using timeout property of $.ajax function like this

```
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=artistname&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 1000,
```

But it's not helpful to me. Can someone tell me, What may be the cause of this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by infinite delay. You have *.audioscrobbler.com allowed in your manifest file right? If you add a callback after the $.ajax call, does that get run?